# Android Search Filter using Action Bar

Tags: listview, android-volley, searchview, android-searchmanager, android-filter

I have implemented a listView Using Volley Library From this tutorial [Custom Volley ListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

After this I have implemented SearchView and search Result Activity like this

BaseActivity

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.enventpc_03.nav11.adapters.NavigationDrawerListAdapter;
import com.enventpc_03.nav11.adater.CustomListAdapter;
import com.enventpc_03.nav11.models.Items;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author dipenp
 *         <p>
 *         This activity will add Navigation Drawer for our application and all the code related to navigation drawer.
 *         We are going to extend all our other activites from this BaseActivity so that every activity will have Navigation Drawer in it.
 *         This activity layout contain one frame layout in which we will add our child activity layout.
 */
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
    protected static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    public CustomListAdapter adapter;
    /**
     * Static variable for selected item position. Which can be used in child activity to know which item is selected from the list.
     */
    protected static int position;
    /**
     * This flag is used just to check that launcher activity is called first time
     * so that we can open appropriate Activity on launch and make list item position selected accordingly.
     */
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;
    /**
     * Frame layout: Which is going to be used as parent layout for child activity layout.
     * This layout is protected so that child activity can access this
     */
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    /**
     * ListView to add navigation drawer item in it.
     * We have made it protected to access it in child class. We will just use it in child class to make item selected according to activity opened.
     */

    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    /**
     * List item array for navigation drawer items.
     */
    protected String[] listArray = {"Home"};
    protected ArrayList<Items> _items;
    /**
     * Base layout node of this Activity.
     */
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    /**
     * Drawer listner class for drawer open, close etc.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    //    handleIntent(getIntent());

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _items = new ArrayList<Items>();
        _items.add(new Items("Home", R.drawable.ic_home1));

        _items.add(new Items("Exit", R.drawable.ic_exit1));

//      //Adding header on list view
//      View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_header_layout, null);
//      mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerListAdapter(this, _items));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
            }
        });

        // Change Action Bar Background Color "may be not works"
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff8c00")));

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.action);



        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                       /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_nirvan,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.open_drawer,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.close_drawer)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */

  /*mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
          getActivity(),
          mDrawerLayout,
          R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
          R.string.navigation_drawer_close
)
  * */ {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
//                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


        /**
         * As we are calling BaseActivity from manifest file and this base activity is intended just to add navigation drawer in our app.
         * We have to open some activity with layout on launch. So we are checking if this BaseActivity is called first time then we are opening our first activity.
         * */
        if (isLaunch) {
            /**
             *Setting this flag false so that next time it will not open our first activity.
             *We have to use this flag because we are using this BaseActivity as parent activity to our other activity.
             *In this case this base activity will always be call when any child activity will launch.
             */
            isLaunch = false;
            openActivity(0);
        }
    }



//  
    /**
     * @param position Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
     */
    protected void openActivity(int position) {

        /**
         * We can set title & itemChecked here but as this BaseActivity is parent for other activity,
         * So whenever any activity is going to launch this BaseActivity is also going to be called and
         * it will reset this value because of initialization in onCreate method.
         * So that we are setting this in child activity.
         */

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
                break;

                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

                break;

            default:

                break;
        }

//      Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
            {
                PerfromSearch(newText);
                return false;
            }

        });
        return true;
    }

    void PerfromSearch(String query) {

        adapter.filter(query);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




}
```

other Activity in which  volley listview listed

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.enventpc_03.nav11.adater.CustomListAdapter;
import com.enventpc_03.nav11.app.AppController;
import com.enventpc_03.nav11.model.Movie;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchPeople extends BaseActivity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = SearchPeople.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    // Movies json url
    private static String url = "http://myulr/demo.php";

    private static String Title = "title";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    public static final String BITMAP_ID = "id";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_search, frameLayout);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

       //For searchResultActivity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
        }






        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

//        // changing action bar color
//        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
//                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("fullname"));


                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("id")

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // your code
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre)).getText().toString();

                bitmap = ((Movie) movieList.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchPeople.this, Details.class);
                intent.putExtra(Title, name);
                intent.putExtra(Location, location);
                intent.putExtra(Description, description);
                intent.putExtra("images", bitmap);


                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }


    private void doMySearch(String query)
    {

        Log.d("Event",query);
        Toast.makeText(SearchPeople.this,query,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SearchPeople.this, UploadActivity.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
        return;
    }


}
```

Now After search it goes to searchresultactivity But I m not getting idea how to print here our filtered search result according to query.

Comment: check the below answer

Answer (score 1):

No need make it complex.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
               PerfromSearch(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

void PerfromSearch(String query) {

    adapter.filter(query);
}
```

**Your Adapter:**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    private List<Movie> movieItemSearched = null;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
        this.movieItemSearched = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        this.movieItemSearched.addAll(movieItems);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // rating
        rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

        // genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

        return convertView;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        movieItems.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            movieItems.addAll(movieItemSearched);
        } else {
            for (Movie wp : movieItemSearched) {
                if (wp.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    movieItems.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```